# How to receive multiple statements and print them out in x86 -64 Assembly (Intel Syntax)

Tags: c, printf, x86-64, sse

I'm fairly new to X86-64 assembly, and was writing a hybrid program (c++ and assembly) to get the user's name, two sides of a triangle, and one angle.
my following code :

Here's the prompts :

```
segment .data

align 16
NamePrompt    db  "--Please enter your name:          ",0
SideAPrompt   db  "--Please enter side A :            ",0
SideBPrompt   db  "--Please enter side B :            ",0
AnglePrompt   db  "--Please enter Angle  :            ",0
Entryconf1    db  "You entered--------------------> %1.5lf and %1.5lf and %1.5lf and %1.5lf ",0
XMM13Value    db  "XMM 13 Value          :      %1.5lf",10,0
andstat       db  ", and ",0
Conclusion    db "The Triangle with side A = %1.5lf"
              db ", Side B = %1.5lf, and Angle= %1.5lf"
              db ", has an Area = sq units \0",0
;Entryconf2   db  "Is that correct------->",0
goodbye       db  "Hope to see you again, Goodbye",10

stringformat db "%s", 0                                     
align 64
```

Here's the uninitialized variables :

```
segment .bss ;uninitialized data

Name      resb 32
SideA     resd 32
SideB     resd 32
Angle     resd 32
TArea     resd 32
```

and here's how I'm obtaining the value of SideA and attempting to add it to xmm13 :

```
;ask for SideA
mov rax, 0
mov rdi, SideAPrompt
call printf
;obtain SideA
mov rax, 0
mov rdi, SideA
mov rsi, 32
mov rdx, [stdin]
call fgets

;save in xmm13
mov rax, SideA
push rax
movsd xmm13, [rsp]
pop rax

;print xmmm13
mov rax,2
mov rdi, XMM13Value
;movsd xmm0, xmm13
call printf
```

I get

```
XMM 13 Value               :      0.00000
```

Also,
I'm trying to print out a statement that confirms all the entries :

```
Entryconf1   db  "You entered--------------------> %1.5lf and %1.5lf and %1.5lf and %1.5lf ",0
```

but when I use the following code :

```
mov qword rax, 2
mov rdi, Entryconf1
mov rsi, SideA
mov rdx, SideB
mov rbx, Angle
call printf
```

it outputs :

```
You entered--------------------> 0.00000 and 0.00000 and 0.00000 and -nan
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: `printf` doesn't take any args in RBX.  It takes double-precision FP args by value in XMM0, XMM1, etc. up to XMM7.  Looks like you're passing garbage, or pointers to strings.  The later can be printed with `%s` conversions, if the pointer is in an integer register.